# java how to check if a list is in another list

Tags: java

I dont want to check if they are equal, but if list a elements are in list b

```
 List<String> ListA //  "yes","no","maybe"
 List<String> ListB // "yes","no","maybe", "perhaps"
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`containsAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method:

```
listB.containsAll(listA)
```

**Note:**

Please, try to follow Java naming conventions, use `someVariable` names for variables and methods. Names like `SomeClass` are used for classes.